# How does a php class determine which class to extend, given there are two class with the same name?

Tags: php, class, extend

Given I have two User classes, one located in /model/User.php and the other located in /assets/User.php

Now I want to have a class which extend the User class from /model/User.php, yet it seems that php is always looking for the one located in /assets/User.php. Any idea how does php determines which class to extend from?

Comment: Do you have an `__autoload()` setup or something registers to `spl_autoload_register()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

`user.php`:

```
class User {
    function someMethod(){}
}
```

`myUser.php`:

```
namespace My;

class User {
    function someMethod(){}
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
include 'user.php';
include 'myuser.php';

$user1 = new User();
$user2 = new \My\User();
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespaces: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Comment: while this is the answer on the question, we don't see it as a good answer if you only provide a link. You can put some code examples, more information, ect. in your answer to make it a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should (if you use) setup appropriately your spl_autoload_register function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to be able autoload the objects in files with same name, bud the names of object can not be the same.

You can distinguish the objects by name and path in which the files are stored.

For instance, you require core class in your bootstrap.php and define autoloading function:

```
    <?php // bootstrap.php

require_once Core.php;
spl_autoload_register(array('Core', 'auto_load'));

$myUserClass = new MyClasses_User() // the required files for the class are loaded because of auto_load, PHP determines the right classes due to naming conventions: DirName_ClassName 

?>


<?php // Core.php

define('DIR_SEPARATOR', '/');

class Core {

  // Autoloading
    public static function auto_load($class, $dir_classes = 'classes')
    {
    $file = str_replace('_', DIR_SEPARATOR, $class); // replace _ by / for path to file

        if ($path = find_file_based_on_class_name($dir_classes, $file))
        {
            // Load the class file
            require $path;
        }
    }

?>

<?php
// classes/Model/User.php
class Model_User {
 // define the class
}
?>

// classes/Assets/User.php
<?php
class Assets_User {
 // define the class
}
?>

// classes/MyClasses/User.php
<?php
class MyClasses_User exdends Model_User {
 // define the class
}
?>
```

Comment: Cool, yet i wonder if the namespace solution would be easier here? Thanks for the answer though!